# Highlight part of a string in a cell content based on a list of predefined words

Tags: r, dt

Hi am trying to highlight list of words in a DT table, its coloring the cell but not the text as per the below code. Is there any way I can color only the word inside text?

Eg: if the data frame has 3 columns in which the text column contains (Financial duty of the product has increase **trifold** in last 3 years) I want to color only trifold and make it bold.

```
DT::datatable(data, filter=list(position = 'top', clear = TRUE), rownames = F,class = 'cell-border stripe compact',
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets =c(1,4))),lengthMenu = c(50,100))) %>% formatDate('date', 'toDateString') %>% formatRound('score',3) %>% formatStyle('text', target = 'row',backgroundColor=styleContain("trifold","yellow"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`formatStyle` won't get you the result you seek, as it'll change the `CSS` properties of the whole element and there is no way to actually stylize some parts of the text. What i'd suggest is to actually change the content of each cell that contains **trifold** and wrap it in some html element, `<mark>` tag seems to be the best fit as by default it will change the `background-color` to yellow you can change the following code to use a span if you want:

```r
# wraps word in the specified tag
wrap_in <- function(.df, column, word, tag){
  class<-""
  if(grepl("\\.", tag)) {
    class <- sub(".+?\\.(.+)", " class='\\1'", tag)
    tag <- sub("\\..+", "", tag)
  }
  .df[[column]] <-  gsub(sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", paste0(word,collapse="|")), sprintf("<%1$s%2$s>\\1</%1$s>", tag, class), .df[[column]])
  .df
}

# create the data.table
mts %>% wrap_in( "text", "trifold", "mark") %>% 
  datatable( escape=F, filter=list(position = 'top', clear = TRUE), rownames = F,class = 'cell-border stripe compact',
              options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets =c(1,4))),lengthMenu = c(50,100))) %>% formatRound('carb',3) -> dt

# prepend css to embolden text found in <mark>
dt  %>%
    htmlwidgets::prependContent(htmltools::tags$style("mark {font-weight: 700;}"))
```

[image]

#### Using a span

```r
mts %>% wrap_in( "text", "trifold", "span.highlight") %>% 
  datatable( escape=F, filter=list(position = 'top', clear = TRUE), rownames = F,class = 'cell-border stripe compact',
              options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets =c(1,4))),lengthMenu = c(50,100))) %>% formatRound('carb',3) %>%
    htmlwidgets::prependContent(htmltools::tags$style("span.highlight {color:yellow;font-weight: 700;}"))
```

[image]

#### DATA

```r
mtcars %>% mutate(text=case_when(cyl==6 ~ "Financial duty of the product has increase trifold in last 3 years", T ~ "Financial duty of the product had no significant increase")) -> mts
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton Abdessabour it worked.Just to add to it.How to add list of words in the function? will paste0('vector of words',collapse='|") work?

Comment: @asaha yes it will, I added it to the answer

Comment: thats amazing. Thanks a lot

Comment: you're welcome, @asaha accept the answer so future readers might find it easily.

Comment: Hi, how can I convert this script to use multiple words with different colors?

Comment: @GabrielCustódioEng basically use multiple calls to `wrap_in` with different classes

Comment: This is a great solution although unfortunately when used in a shiny app it gives the following error `Warning in renderWidget(instance) :
  Ignoring prepended content; prependContent can't be used in a Shiny render call` Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: @TheDza can you provide code that reproduces the error

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk the problem was with the `dt  %>%
    htmlwidgets::prependContent(htmltools::tags$style("mark {font-weight: 700;}"))` command in the above. Shiny can't seem to use this. I found a work around though.  Remove the line that uses `prependContent` and in the ui section add `tags$head(                              tags$style(HTML("mark {font-weight: 700;}"))),`